# how to Spread the windows in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, gestures

how can I **scale (spread) all the windows** in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. On the same PC when I windows when I scroll away three fingers touch all the windows are spread.
Suggest any gesture client.

Answer (score 2):

Pressing `Super+W` will zoom out to display all windows. From there you may quickly select another window. Additionally pressing `Ctrl+Alt` and a number on the numpad allows you to quickly reposition windows.

You can also activate these commands with touchpad gestures using *Easystroke*. To install easystroke in *16.04*, open a terminal and type:

`sudo apt-get install easystroke`

Or, search for it in the Ubuntu store. From there you may configure several gestures on the touchpad such as one to press `Super+W`. To my knowledge though, Easystroke only supports single-touch gestures and requires a button to be held to activate it.